# how to load a list of items from a website into an android app ?

Tags: android, parsing, web, jsoup

a list like, a list of contents of an e-commerce site, how to load that in android app. 
I have tried with the Jsoup class, and htmlcleaner libraries.

Comment: You need to learn Json Tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `jsoup` library to parse the HTML page and store the values locally.

Next, in your activity XML, define a `ListView`.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list1" />
```

In your `Activity` class, create a reference to the `ListView` object.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
```

Let us now parse the HTML page and get the required data. For this, we will use the `jsoup` library inside an `ASyncTask` as we don't want to block the main UI thread.

```
private class HTMLParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     protected void doInBackground(Void... args0) {
         //Do your thing here
         }
         return null;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         //Store in local database
     }
 }
```

Now, create a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and then populate the `ListView` by setting the adapter to it.

```
listView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

make an asyncTask where you call your web service and fetch your data.

```
    private class callWebSerices extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // make your server request
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    //fetch your data and bind to list }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

you can execute this task by new callWebSerices().execute()

if you have image to show try to use async image loader library and i can notice Universal Image Loader [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)